# Python Plotly: How to avoid truncated chart

Tags: python, plotly, annotations

I have a chart with an annotation that is 10 lines long that is truncated. I tried increasing the height of the layout and it only increased the height of the chart but the truncation issue persists.
I've included an image of what I mean below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to avoid the truncation is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
I tried with suggested fig.update_yaxes(domain=[0.25, 1.0]) the result now looks like:
[image]

Comment: You can specify the domain of the graph in plotly, so try this. `fig.update_yaxes(domain=[0.25, 1.0])` See [this](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#side-by-side-subplot-lowlevel-api)

Comment: Can't seem to figure it out with domains... After trying with the example above I'm only seeing the volume chart with the same truncation; seen in updated description above.

Comment: If the area of the graph is irrelevant, then your issue is simply the low position of the string annotation. I need your code as well as the output chart. In the reference, see [Absolute Value Text Annotation](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#positioning-text-annotations-absolutely) and [Adding Strings with reference to axes](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#adding-annotations-referenced-to-an-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's partially due to a margin issue. Try this:

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=20,
                              b=200, #play around with the spacing as needed
                              l=20,
                              r=20)
                  )
```